# Struggling with including Headers in another header file (C++)

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to include Toolkit.h into Neptune Actions.h

Toolkit (Libraries)

Actions (Functions)

When the code runs, none of the functions in Neptune Actions.h are recognized by the compiler which means it didn't recieve Toolkit.h. How come the libraries in toolkit aren't recognized in Actions? What am I missing or doing wrong? 
Thanks for your help!

*Note: The same effect takes place in Project Neptune.cpp but I assume it's because Action's can't retrieve the toolkit*

Neptune Actions Below. Included: `init()`

Here the `gl, GL` codes produce these errors (sample):

1>c:\users\jjsun\source\repos\project neptune\project neptune\neptune actions.h(79): error C2065: 'GL_SMOOTH': undeclared identifier

1>c:\users\jjsun\source\repos\project neptune\project neptune\neptune actions.h(79): error C3861: 'glShadeModel': identifier not found

```
#ifndef Neptune Actions_H_INCLUDED
#define Neptune Actions_H_INCLUDED

// ToolKit not moving into both Source/Project
#include "Neptune ToolKit.h"
#include <iostream>

void init(void)
{
    // Clear Color + Shade Model
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    // Star Initialization
    glNewList(1, GL_COMPILE);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++) {
            if (((i + j) % 2) == 0) {
                glVertex3f(100 * i, 100 * j, 0.0);
            }
        }
    }
    glEnd();
    glEndList();

    // Material Specs
    GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1 };
    GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 128.0 };
    GLfloat lightDiffuse[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    GLfloat lmodel_ambient[] = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.7, 0.0 };

    // Light 0 Initialized.
    GLfloat light0[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1 };
    GLfloat light_position[] = { 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, -100.0 };

    // Light 1 Initialized 
    GLfloat light1[] = { 0.3, 0.2, 0.8 };
    GLfloat light_position1[] = { -0.3, 1.0, 0.3, -50.0 };

    GLfloat light2[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat light_position2[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    // Light 0
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

    // Light 1
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, light1);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light_position1);

    // Spotlight Light 2
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT2, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, light2);

    // Mat Specs Implmentations.
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);

    //Ambient surrounding light on object.
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, lmodel_ambient);

    // Enable Lighting and Depth
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    //glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT2);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // Enable AntiAliased Lines
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_DONT_CARE);
    glLineWidth(1.5);
}
```

ToolKit.h Below

```
#ifndef Neptune ToolKit_H
#define Neptune ToolKit_H

#include <iostream>
//GL/Windows
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
#include <glut.h>
 //Texture 
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"
 //Math
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
```

Comment: All questions on stackoverflow.com must include all pertinent information ***in plain text***. Images are not readable with text-only readers. You need to [edit] your question and show all relevant information as plain text.

Comment: What are the actual exact names of your files? You should not have a space in your include guard. `#define Neptune ToolKit_H` will replace all mentions of `Neptune` with `ToolKit_H`. Use a single identifier like `NEPTUNE_TOOLKIT_H`. It is custom to write preprocessor macros with all-capital letters. Having an additional identifier after `#ifndef Neptune` is also not allowed, some compilers are just too nice and don't complain with an error (but probably a warning)

Comment: The file containing the `void init(void)` definition seems to be a header file. Function definitions belong into the implementation file, not header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your Neptune Action.h header file to something like Neptune_Action.h and update your header guards after that